# glossaries: display `see` reference but not page numbers

Tags: cross-referencing, page-numbering, glossaries

I am trying to display the `see` cross references but not the page numbers in my document.

I understood that it's impossible with the means provided by standard, so I tried to use
 `\renewcommand*{\glossaryentrynumbers}[1]{XXX}`
(replace `XXX` with various things that I tried)

to fit my code. Unfortunately my lack of Latex knowledge is not very helpful.

What do I have to put instead of `XXX` to display the cross references, but not the page numbers?

---

Here is an example (sorry, I thought it was clear what I meant):

file: `glossary.tex`

```
\newacronym[see={{cutg}}]{cut}{CUT}{Code Under Test}
\newglossaryentry{cutg}{name={CUT},
    description={\acrfull{cut} refers to the part of the source code that is actually tested. It is a part of the entire source ode and modified before test generation. The tests are generated for the CUT, rather than the original source code. The CUT can be a function, a file or an entire component}
}
```

file: `report.tex`

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}


%Glossary
\usepackage[xindy,acronym]{glossaries} % nomain, if you define glossaries in a file, and you use \include{INP-00-glossary}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\makeglossaries
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=List of Terms]
\loadglsentries[main]{../../glossary}
\renewcommand{\acronymfont}[1]{\textit{#1}} % make acronms italics
\renewcommand{\firstacronymfont}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\seename}{Glossary:} % What text should be used for the see-field
%\renewcommand*{\glossaryentrynumbers}[1]{\glsseelist} % turn off ugly numbers (don't use the option for usepackage, otherwise see doesn't work)
\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

When I compile, I produce this: [image: Example with highlight]

How can I get rid of the page numbers (highlighted through red rectangles in the image)?
I tried renewing the command that creates `\glossaryentrynumbers`, since the option `[nonumberlist]` apparently does the same (as far as I know, it calls

```
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentrynumbers}[1]{}
```

so my though process was that if I redefine it myself to only contain the see-list, then I should be sorted.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I am talking about the `glossaries` package that offers the `[nonumberlist]` option on import. However, `nonumberlist` also hides the cross-references defined with `see={otherGlossaryEntry}`. I would like to display cross-references but still hide the page numbers.

Comment: you're correct, i did misunderstand.  however, a little research shows that the `nonumberlist` is used in the `glossaries` user manual (`glossaries-user.pdf`) for the intro "glossary" (p.8) that does include cross-references.  you might want to look into the file `glossaries-user.tex` (should be in the `doc` area of your tex live installation) to see how that's done.

Comment: It seems to me that the intro glossary (p.8) does not have any "See also:" links.  However, I now looked around and found that `\glsseelist` might be what I am looking for. 
So my code: `\renewcommand*{\glossaryentrynumbers}[1]{\glsseelist}` unfortunately leads to
 `! Missing \endcsname inserted.  
<to be read again>   
                   \relax 
l.28 \glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{1}}}\relax
                                           \glsresetentrylist` and I don't really understand how to 'extract' the list.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Either use the first option listed in [Cross-Referencing Entries](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:crossref) or use the `seeautonumberlist` package option with the `see` key.

Answer (score 4):

The `seeautonumberlist` package option is designed for use with the `nonumberlist` option to enable the location list for entries with the `see` key, but this is only intended when the entry with the `see` key is a synonym that's not used in the document (otherwise you get the rest of the location list appearing as well for that entry).

For example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,seeautonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample1}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\newglossaryentry{sample2}{name={another sample},
 description={another example},
 see={sample1}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}

A \gls{sample1}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of glossary with no location list but cross-reference is present]

If I add a reference to `sample2` in the document like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,seeautonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample1}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\newglossaryentry{sample2}{name={another sample},
 description={another example},
 see={sample1}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}

A \gls{sample1} and \gls{sample2}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Then the page number also appears for `sample2`:

[image: image of glossary with page number appearing before cross-reference]

In this case, it's simpler to move the cross-reference into the description:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample1}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\newglossaryentry{sample2}{name={another sample},
 description={another example, \emph{see} \gls{sample1}}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}

A \gls{sample1} and \gls{sample2}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of glossary with no location lists]

(The `glossaries` user manual uses `\gls` in the description field in a similar manner.)

Another possibility is to use `\glsseeformat` which can accept a comma-separated list of labels and is the way the cross-reference is displayed in the location list when using the `see` key. If you use this command, remember that there are two mandatory arguments. The last one is provided for the benefit of `makeindex` and, although ignored by LaTeX, must be present.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample1}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\newglossaryentry{sample2}{name={another sample},
 description={another example, \glsseeformat{sample1,sample3}{}}}

\newglossaryentry{sample3}{name={third sample},
 description={yet another example}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}

A \gls{sample1} and \gls{sample2}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of resulting glossary]

The optional argument allows you to override the "see" tag:

```
\glsseeformat[see also]{sample1,sample3}{}
```

For abbreviations, you'll need to override the default description for styles like `long-short`. For example:

```
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newacronym[description={an example, see \gls{sample1}}]{anex}{anex}{an example}
```

**Edit:** Another possibility is to use the [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package which stores the value of the `see` key (the base `glossaries` package doesn't do this). This means that the value of the `see` key can be accessed in the glossary when the number list has been suppressed. Version 1.06 of `glossaries-extra` adds a convenient to use command `\glsxtrusesee{`*label*`}` which makes it easier to access the value. This command does nothing if the `see` key is empty for *label*, otherwise it does `\glsseeformat[`*tag*`]{`*xr list*`}{}`, where the tag and cross-reference list are obtained from the `see` field.

The post-description hook can be modified to add this. For example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,nopostdot=false]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample1}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\newglossaryentry{sample2}{name={another sample},
 description={another example},
 see={sample1}}

\renewcommand*{\glsxtrpostdescgeneral}{%
 \ifglshasfield{see}{\glscurrententrylabel}
 {, \glsxtrusesee{\glscurrententrylabel}}%
 {}%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}

A \gls{sample1} and \gls{sample2}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of example]

The `glossaries-extra` package also conveniently lets the `see` key trigger the automatic use of `\glsxtraddallcrossrefs` at the end of the document. This means that the following only requires the build sequence `latex`, `makeglossaries`, `latex` to include all the cross-references in the document:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,nopostdot=false]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\glsxtrpostdescgeneral}{%
 \ifglshasfield{see}{\glscurrententrylabel}
 {, \glsxtrusesee{\glscurrententrylabel}}%
 {}%
}

\newglossaryentry{sample1}{name={sample 1},description={an example}}
\newglossaryentry{sample2}{name={sample 2},description={an
example},see={sample1}}
\newglossaryentry{sample3}{name={sample 3},description={an
example},see={sample2}}
\newglossaryentry{sample4}{name={sample 4},description={an
example},see=[see also]{sample2,sample3}}

\begin{document}
\gls{sample4}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of glossary]

Comment: @S.K. Does it solves your problem? If yes please accept to close this question.